# How to Encode ( utf-8) in Pandas (Excel as source)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pymongo-3.x

I am trying to read from excel and load into Mongodb using Pymongo.

The Error I got cannot is "encode object: , of type: <class 'pandas._libs.missing.NAType'>", when researched, I was told to use utf-8-sign format to insert it into monogodb, but in pandas dataframe there is no option to use utf-8

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import Parameters
import pandasql as pf
import json
import pymongo
import xlrd
from pathlib import Path
import os
import constants
try:
    class conn:
        def __init__(self):
            client = pymongo.MongoClient( "mongodb://" + constants.USER_NAME + ":" + constants.PWD + constants.server + constants.CA_CERTIFICATES_PATH)
            db = client[Parameters.STG_QC_Hub_Files]
            week="08-02-2021"
            out_col = db[Parameters.col]
            filename = "1.xlsx"
            path1 = Path('//test3'+'/'+filename)
            data_load_date = datetime.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
            df1=pd.read_excel(path1,sheet_name="AU-ARCM Details",keep_default_na=False)
         #   df1 = pd.read_excel(xls+filename,keep_default_na=False,encoding='utf-8-sig')
          #  df1 = pd.read_csv(xls,keep_default_na=False,encoding='utf-8-sig').iloc[:, : 86]
            df1["Week"]=week
            df1["Data Load Date"]=data_load_date
            df1 = df1.astype('string')
         #   df1.index = df1.index.str.encode('utf-8')
            df1=df1.drop(['Source.Name'], axis=1)
            records = json.loads(df1.T.to_json()).values()

            out_col.insert_many(df1.to_dict('records'))
            print("Imported  File  " +str(filename)+" with " +str(len(records) )+ "  records")
    c = conn()
except  Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Traceback:

```
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\ReMs\venv\lib\site-packages\pymongo\message.py", line 1323, in _do_batched_op_msg
    operation, command, docs, check_keys, ack, opts, ctx)
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: <NA>, of type: <class 'pandas._libs.missing.NAType'>
```

Comment: Please post the traceback - probably easist to remove the try/except and grab it there.

Comment: Agreed - [tracebacks](https://realpython.com/python-traceback/) are super important for debugging

Comment: Added tracebacks, please check

Comment: this isn't the full traceback. can you post the whole thing?

Answer (score 1):

You have some blank cells in your spreadsheet that pandas has its own type (NAT) for; pymongo doesn't know what to do with this type, hence the error. You will need to remove any of these in order to load the values into mongodb using the method you are using.

Consider something like this just before you attempt the insert:

```
import numpy as np
df1 = df1.replace(np.nan, None)
```